# KendoUI Mobile switch and datasource

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, kendo-datasource

I'm trying to have a list of items displayed using a listview, something like:

```
<div data-role="view" data-model="my_model">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-bind="source: ds" data-template="list-tmpl"></ul>
</div>
```

Where I have a `view` using a model called `my_model` and a `listview` where the `source` is bound to `ds`.

My model is something like:

```
var my_model = kendo.observable({
    ds: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: readData,
            update: updateData,
            create: updateData,
            remove: updateData
        },
        pageSize: 10,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "id",
                fields: {
                    id: { type: "number" },
                    name: { type: "string" },
                    active: { type: "boolean" }
                }
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Each item includes an `id`, a `name` (that is a `string`) and a `boolean` named `active`.

The template used to render each element is:

```
<script id="list-tmpl" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    <span>#= name # : #= active #</span>
    <input data-role="switch" data-bind="checked: active"/>
</script>
```

Where I display the `name` and (for debugging) the value of `active`. In addition, I render a `switch` bound to `active`.

You should see something like:

[image]

The problems observed are:

1. If you click on a switch you will see that the value of `active` next to the `name` changes its value (as expected) but if then, you pick another switch, the value (neither next to `name` nor in the `DataSource`) is not updated (despite the value of the switch is correctly updated).
2. The `update` handler in the DataSource is never invoked (not even for the first chosen switch and despite the DataSource for that first toggled switch is updated).

You can check it in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/K7wEC/

How do I make that the DataSource gets updated and `update` handler invoked?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the solution was pretty simple: set `autoSync` to `true` in the `DataSource` definition.

```
var my_model = kendo.observable({
    ds: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: readData,
            update: updateData,
            create: updateData,
            remove: updateData
        },
        autoSync: true,
        pageSize: 10,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "id",
                fields: {
                    id: { type: "number" },
                    name: { type: "string" },
                    active: { type: "boolean" }
                }
            }
        }
    })
});
```

See the JSFiddle modified here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/K7wEC/1/